# SwiftUI - List item can't read editMode environment variable of their parent when wrapped in a NavigationLink

Tags: list, swiftui, environment-variables, edit

I have a list with items that serve as navigation links. I want those items to change when their parent list is in edit mode.

Because they are wrapped in Navigation Links, the items are having issues or seem to be unable to read the `@Environment(\.editMode)` of their parent. If you remove the navigation link, they work as expected.

I'd like to continue using the native `EditButton()` and avoid eg. creating and passing my own state variable that holds an `EditMode` to the child row views, since doing so causes issues with the smooth animation into and out of edit mode. Is this possible?

[image: Shows discrepenecy]

Heres an MRE:

```
import SwiftUI

struct DummyListView: View {
    var items = ["item 1", "item 2", "item 3"]

    var body: some View {
        NavigationView {
            List {
                Section(header: Text("Basic Rows")){
                    ForEach(items, id: \.self){ item in
                        ItemRow(itemName: item)
                    }
                    .onDelete { index in
                        // delete functionality
                    }
                }
                
                Section(header: Text("Wrapped in Navigation link")){
                    ForEach(items, id: \.self){ item in
                        NavigationLink(destination: Text("Hwllo")){
                            ItemRow(itemName: item)
                        }
                    }
                    .onDelete { index in
                        // delete functionality
                    }
                }
            }
            .listStyle(InsetGroupedListStyle())
            .toolbar {
                ToolbarItem(placement: .navigationBarTrailing) {
                    EditButton()
                }
            }
        }
        
    }
    
    struct ItemRow: View {
        @Environment(\.editMode) var editMode
        let itemName: String
        
        var body: some View {
            HStack {
                Text(itemName)
                
                Spacer()
                
                Text(editMode?.wrappedValue == .active ? "Active" : "Inactive")
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I can see the behavior, but I am not sure what you are trying to accomplish. The edit state really is just for that view. Can you imagine having one view edit another? We aren't talking about a shared model, as that would update the views in normal course.

Comment: Essentially I have an button on my list rows (that are wrapped in navigation links) that I only want to show when the list is in edit mode. It seems silly to me that I can’t extract the list items into a subview and allow them to read the state of the list. Especially since it works when the list items aren’t in a nav link.